# Can I use elementary OS on a server?

Tags: system-installation

Suppose we want to use a Tower Server as a Workstation. The Tower Server would have server motherboard, 16-cores, 200+ GB RAM, etc.

(1) I really like the look and feel of elementary OS, can I get elementary OS to install on the Server?

(2) Separately, I want to use a 4-monitor say based on a NVIDIA Quadro graphics card. Any compatibility issues with elementary OS? I read a few places online where they had trouble with multiple monitors with elementary OS.

Comment: So far I know elementary OS is designed for client PC's. Also I wonder why you would want to add 4 monitors on your server? Isn't the whole point of a server to focus on the task it is given? Like HTTP, FTP and other services?

Comment: have absolutely no idea why you could want that

Comment: OP, please ask separate questions separately

Comment: @Thomas15v, i want to use the server as a workstation, multi-CPUs in particular

Comment: Than I see no problem in using elementary. I indeed also read that multi-screen can be an issue as the plank will only appear on one screen. But their are workarounds for that.